# User input to update variables when multiple objects involved

Tags: java, class, object, input, methods

I'm currently learning java and starting on methods, classes and objects. I'm attempting to code a simple program to have set values for 2 separate employee's at a company that would then allow for user input to alter certain variables of a specific object. The variables needing to be updated via user input will be the MonthlySalary and FirstName of the object employee2. I'm not really sure how to structure the user input part and I'm at a loss trying to find a solution.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args ){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // Create 2 Employee objects
        Employee employee1 = new Employee( "Jane", "Doe", 5000 );
        Employee employee2 = new Employee( "John", "Bloggs", 4500 );

        // Do other steps (not requiring input)

        // Ask for user input of Employee 2's new first name
        System.out.println( "Please enter new first name for Employee 2: \n");
        String input = employee2.newFirstName();
        
        // repeat above to set Employee 2's new salary then display new information


   }
}
```

With the Class file Employee.java

```java
public class Employee
{
   private String firstName;           // Employee's First Name
   private String lastName;            // Employee's Last Name
   private double monthlySalary;       // Employee's Monthly Salary

// Employee constructor
   public Employee( String initFirstName, String initLastName, double initMonthlySalary ) 
   {
      firstName = initFirstName;
      lastName = initLastName;
      if (initMonthlySalary > 0)
          monthlySalary = initMonthlySalary;
      else
          monthlySalary = 0;
   }

    public Employee( )
    {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        monthlySalary = 0;
    }

// Method to assign the employee's First Name
   public void setFirstName( String newFirstName )                   
   {
      firstName = newFirstName;
   }

// Method to assign the employee's Monthly Salary
   public void setMonthlySalary( double newMonthlySalary )           
   {
      if (newMonthlySalary > 0) monthlySalary = newMonthlySalary;
   }

// Other required methods

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are struggling to take input from the console.

```
System.out.println("Please enter new first name for Employee 2: ");
    String firstName = input.next();
    employee2.setFirstName(firstName);

    System.out.println("Please enter new Salary for Employee 2: ");
    double salary = input.nextDouble();
    employee2.setMonthlySalary(salary);
```

This will work for you. And please go through the basic syntaxes first. Because otherwise you are wasting your own time banging your head for this kind of syntactical doubts.

Comment: Thank you and I will revisit before moving forward.